# Angular js Passport example is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to follow this example:

- source : https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport
- demo website: http://angular-passport.herokuapp.com/

I copied and pasted to my app and server almost same.

Routes work (in server side and client side too)

When I tried to log in or sign up I get a 404 error from server.

here is my server-side routes part.

I checked `app.get('/robots.txt')` works.

and this is routes part for login (that gave me 404 error):

```
app.post('/auth/session', session.login);
```

but I tried:

```
app.post('/auth/session', function(req,res){
    console.log('here is session requested');
    res.sendfile('robots.txt');
});
```

This code for checking whether server does respond well.

But still I got 404 error.

How can I fix this works? Ir how can I test this post routings with console.log or, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try using postman chrome extension for debugging RESTful api s
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may just be a simple path adjustment - sendFile requires a full path to be defined (you have provided a relative path by just using the filename) - try this:

```
res.sendFile('robots.txt', { root: __dirname + '/' });
```

Note that res.sendfile (lowercase 'f') has been deprecated and replaced with res.sendFile in Express 4.